# Transform Nested XML

Tags: python, xml, csv

I am currently looking to parse out a nested XML into a pandas Datatable so I can generate a CSV with each column being an element name and the value of that being the element text but I am having some issues parsing the information out. Below is an example of the nested XML and what I have tried.

The below XML can be quite large with hundreds of different records. This is what I tried:

```py
##Import modules
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree

tree = ET.parse("File.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for subelement in root:
    for subsub in subelement:
        print(subsub.tag,",", subsub.text, subsub.attrib, subsub.items())

for subelement in root:
    for subsub in subelement:
        for subsubsub in subsub:
            print(subsubsub.tag,",", subsubsub.text, subsubsub.attrib)
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<test1 xmlns="test.xsd">
    <test2 ID="123123123" test3="123123">
        <test3>Separate</test3>
        <test4>AA</test4>
        <Comments>BB</Comments>
        <test5>
            <test6 ID="123123">
                <test3>today</test3>
                <test7>123 street</test7>
            </test6>
        </test5>
        <test8>
            <test10 ID="434234">
                <test3>type of work</test3>
                <test9>test work</test9>
            </test10>
        </test8>
        <test11>
            <test12 ID="234234234">
                <test3>Social</test3>
                <test14>test</test14>
            </test12>
            <test12 ID="123123">
                <test3>Something Here</test3>
                <test13>Some date</test13>
                <test14>123123124433</test14>
            </test12>
        </test11>
        <test15>
            <test16 ID="6456456456">
                <test3>Something Something</test3>
                <test14>746745636</test14>
            </test16>
        </test15>
    </test2>
    <test2 ID="353453245" test3="list of something">
        <test3>Somewhere</test3>
        <test4>Someone</test4>
        <Comments>Some comment</Comments>
        <test5>
            <test6 ID="567456756">
                <test3>Not today</test3>
                <test7>5634643643</test7>
                <test17>Some Info</test17>
                <test19>Somewhere</test19>
                <test18>63243333</test18>
            </test6>
        </test5>
        <test11>
            <test12 ID="456436346">
                <test3>Pattern</test3>
                <test14>436346346</test14>
            </test12>
            <test12 ID="4364356">
                <test3> ID</test3>
                <test14>5674567457</test14>
            </test12>
            <test12 ID="123123123443">
                <test3>Other ID</test3>
                <test13>54234532452345</test13>
                <test14>231423532452345</test14>
            </test12>
        </test11>
        <test15>
            <test16 ID="34252345">
                <test3>None test</test3>
                <test14>456436436346</test14>
            </test16>
        </test15>
    </test2>
</test1>
```

**Update** So would the full code look something like this?

```
###TEST USING EXAMPLE HOTLIST
with open("file.csv", "w", newline='') as fout:
    header = ['test3','test4','test7','test9','test13','test14','test17','test18','test19','Comments']
    csvout = csv.DictWriter(fout, fieldnames=header)
    csvout.writeheader()
    row = {}
    for _, elem in ET.iterparse('file.xml'):
        # strip the namespace from the element tag name; e.g. {Test.xsd}test14 > test14
        tag = re.sub("^{.*?}", "", elem.tag)
        if tag == 'test2':
            if len(row) != 0:
                print(row)
                csvout.writerow(row)
                row = {}
        if len(elem) == 0:
            text = elem.text
            old = row.get(tag)
            if old is None:
                # first occurrence of the tag
                row[tag] = text
            elif isinstance(old, str):
                # second occurrence of the tag
                row[tag] = [old, text]
            else:
                # already a list
                old.append(text)
```

Comment: Does that mean a single row, with all the data captured in columns? Please provide a sample CSV given that sample XML.

Comment: @ZachYoung Let me compile what the final output would look like and I will upload it, but yes, every single tag needs to be a column header and the text and/or attributes need to be values on a single row for each record

Comment: "... a single row for each record"... In the XML, what's a _record_? Is `test1` a record and everything below belongs on one row, and there will one CSV row for this XML? Is `test2` a record, which would results in two CSV rows for this XML?

Comment: Also, a number of element names are re-used through a test, `test2[1]/test5/test6` and `test2[1]/test8/test10` both contain a `test3`. How will that look/be resolved?

Comment: Container elements (e.g. test2, test5, test6, test8, test15, etc.) have only sub-child elements and no text content so assume they will NOT appear as column names in the desired CSV output.

Comment: Yes, the update will capture all the text values of the XML into columns matching the tag names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nested XML you can use [iterparse()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) function to iterate over all elements in the XML. You would then need to have logic to handle the elements depending on what tag it's looking at to add to a dictionary object to export as a row.

```python
for _, elem in ET.iterparse('file.xml'):
    if len(elem) == 0:
        print(f'{elem.tag} {elem.attrib} text={elem.text}')
    else:
        print(f'{elem.tag} {elem.attrib}')
```

To create a row in a CSV file from the element text then can do something like this. If, for example, the "test2" marks the beginning of a new record then that can be used to write the record to a new row and clear the dictionary for the next record.

If want to output all or some attributes then need to add a few lines of code for that. If attribute names have the same name as element name or multiple elements have same attribute (e.g. ID) then need to address that in your code.

```python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re
import csv

with open("out.csv", "w", newline='') as fout:
    header = ['test3','test4','test7','test9','test13','test14','test17','test18','test19','Comments']
    csvout = csv.DictWriter(fout, fieldnames=header)
    csvout.writeheader()
    row = {}
    for _, elem in ET.iterparse('test.xml'):
        # strip the namespace from the element tag name; e.g. {Test.xsd}test14 > test14
        tag = re.sub("^{.*?}", "", elem.tag)
        if tag == 'test2':
            if len(row) != 0:
                print(row)
                csvout.writerow(row)
                row = {}
        if len(elem) == 0:
            row[tag] = elem.text
```

**Output:**

```
{'test3': 'Something Something', 'test4': 'AA', 'Comments': 'BB', 'test7': '123 street', 'test9': 'test work', 'test14': '746745636', 'test13': 'Some date'}
{'test3': 'None test', 'test4': 'Someone', 'Comments': 'Some comment', 'test7': '5634643643', 'test17': 'Some Info', 'test19': 'Somewhere', 'test18': '63243333', 'test14': '456436436346', 'test13': '54234532452345'}
```

**CSV Output:**

```
test3,test4,test7,test9,test13,test14,test17,test18,test19,Comments
Something Something,AA,123 street,test work,Some date,746745636,,,,BB
None test,Someone,5634643643,,54234532452345,456436436346,Some Info,63243333,Somewhere,Some comment
```

**Update:**

If want to handle duplicate tags and create a list of values then try something like this:

```python
if len(elem) == 0:
    text = elem.text
    old = row.get(tag)
    if old is None:
        # first occurrence
        row[tag] = text
    elif isinstance(old, str):
        # second occurrence > create list
        row[tag] = [old, text]
    else:
        old.append(text)
```

Comment: Hi - thank you so much for your reply. I haven't forgotten about this. I am trying to interpret the script as I am a bit new to Python and need some time to understand what is happening. I am compiling a list of additional questions to better understand the script.

Comment: thank you again for your reply. I am a Python novice so I want to run this by you since my final product needs to be a CSV file with the column headers being every single  elem.tag (each record could have different amount of elem.tag), and row values for each column header being either elem.text or elem.attrib( when elem.attrib exists).
My initial thought is to manually create a DT with every single possible header then appending to each row as the script loops through elements. Not sure how to distinguish between records and how to handle column header variation between records.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide example how the XML structure should map to a row in CSV so can better tailor an example for that. Does every "test2" element map to one row or is a "row" at a child element level?

Comment: I don't know how to upload an excel file here so hopefully this helps.
These are the column headers:
Test2, test3, test4, Comments, test5, test6, test3, test7, test17, test19, test18, test8, test10, test3, test9, test11, test12, test3, test14, test12, test3, test13, test14, test15, test16, test3, test14

Basically, everything that says test should be the values. Please note that different records might have different test elements. For example records 1 could have test1, test,2  but record 2 could have all of those and test4,test,5

Comment: So I was thinking of initially getting the unique number of elements , the full range and making them as column headers and then filling in the values as it loops through.

Comment: @Sasho updated code in answer to create a CSV using element names as columns and text as the values. Think this is closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for this.  A couple of questions:
1- Where is "row" coming from, I don't see it initialized or used anywhere except for the IF statement

2-  what is the "_" before the comma in the For loop?

Comment: `row = {}` right before the for loop. "_" before the comma because don't care about the first item in iterparse() result.

Comment: I am trying to avoid extended discussions in comments based on the recommendations of this site but I don't have enough reputation to do so yet so I am sorry.
Thank you for the feedback. A question. So there could exist multiple columns with the same name (for example test3). If you notice, test3 column has a value of "something something" in the output when before that it has the value "Separate".  Correct me if I am wrong but this unique header is happening because row is an array?  how do I ensure that all column headers are returned even if they have the same name? (maybe a list?)

Comment: @Sasho Updated answer to create lists for duplicate tags.

Comment: I added the final code as an update to for review. I tried running it but it was only generating headers, currently trying to troubleshoot but i might have added your last update incorrectly.

Comment: I thin that this worked.  the results are a bit odd in excel but I think I can do text to column and fix that because each column have a list of values in there but its no big deal at all. THANK YOU so much for this help, this is truly fantastic code, I set the above as the answer but are there any other ways to give you "credits" or thumbs up that I am missing?

Comment: I accepted the answer but it's telling me that I need 15 reputation to upvote lol which I currently don't have yet

Comment: Boom!! I just added the Upvote. Thanks again for your help :)